# CakePHP how to pass a foreign key

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have 2 tables: table bien  and table disponibilite. I want to retrieve the id of the table Bien and put it automatically in the  table disponibilite but it doesn't work.
this is my code

```
public function add($id = null ) {
    $this->loadModel("Bien");
    $biens = $this->Disponibilitebien->Bien->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('Bien.idBien'=>$id)));
     $this-> set('biens',$biens);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Disponibilitebien->create();
        if ($this->Disponibilitebien->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The disponibilitebien has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The disponibilitebien could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

}
```

this is the table :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSBmK.png)

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, do you want to INSERT the Bien.id into the Disponibilite table in the column bien_id ?

Comment: yeah sorry i'm not food in english :(

Answer (score 0):

the id is equal to

```
$biens['Bien']['id'];
```

or

```
$this->viewVars['biens']['Bein']['id'];
```